# jQuery function that checks whether multiple div's data-indices are ordered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm randomly outputting the order of divs that each have a data-index. I'm using jQuery-ui for its sortable method so users can rearrange the order of the divs. How can I make it so that, when you press a submit button, a function is called to check whether the data-index of each element is ordered or not?

The DOM structure looks like this:

```
<div class="sequence_boxes sortable sortable_area ui-sortable">
  <div class="box" data-index="0">..</div>
  <div class="box" data-index="1">..</div>
  <div class="box" data-index="2">..</div>
  <div class="box" data-index="3">..</div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('.sequencing').append('<div class="sequence_boxes sortable sortable_area"></div>');

$('.sequence_option').each(function (i) {
    $('<div class="box"></div>').appendTo($('.sequence_boxes')).append(this);
    $(this).attr("data-index", i);
    $(this).parent().attr('data-index', i);

});

$('.sequence_boxes').each(function () {

    // get current div
    var $div_parent = $(this);

    // get array of childs in parent div
    var $divsArr = $div_parent.children('.box');

    // sort array of childs in parent div (#sponsors) randomly
    $divsArr.sort(function (a, b) {

        // Get a random number between 0 and 10
        var temp = parseInt(Math.random() * 10);

        // Get 1 or 0, whether temp is odd or even
        var isOddOrEven = temp % 2;

        // Get +1 or -1, whether temp greater or smaller than 5
        var isPosOrNeg = temp > 5 ? 1 : -1;

        // Return -1, 0, or +1
        return (isOddOrEven * isPosOrNeg);
    })

    // append child items to parent
    .appendTo($div_parent);
});



$('.sortable_area').sortable({
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    forceHelperSize: false,
    connectWith: ".sequence_boxes",
    scrollSensitivity: 200,
    scrollSpeed: 40,
    placeholder: "ui-sortable-placeholder",
    cursor: "move",
    distance: 0.5,
    delay: 100,
    opacity: 0.6,
    tolerance: "pointer",


}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to bind JS to a button or how to write JS to do the check that you're asking about?

Comment: @TylerH I know how to set an onclick. I need the function to actually check if it's ordered that I can place inside the onclick block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple:

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/duwor/1/edit)

```
  var correct_index = 0;
  $('.box').each(function(){
    var current_index = $(this).data('index');
    if(current_index != correct_index) {
      alert('Out of order');
      return false;
    } 
    correct_index++;
  });
```

### UPDATE:

**[This](http://jsbin.com/duwor/2/edit)** is a more consistent implementation:

Your case:

```
$('.sequence_boxes .box').isOrdered('asc', 'index');
```

#### Usage:

```
$(selector).isOrdered(order, data, [fail], [success]);
```

});

- order: 'asc' or 'desc' (ordered by).
- data: 'index' ... data-whatever (your data type).
- fail [optional]: a callback function to be executed if a node is out of order (the fail node is the first argument).
- success [optional]: a callback function to be executed if everything is in order.

Source:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  isOrdered: function(orderBy, data, succ, fail){
    var correct_index = 0, o = 1, f = false, t = this;
    if(orderBy == 'desc') {
      correct_index = this.length - 1;
      o = -1;        
    }
    this.each(function(){
      var current_index = $(this).data('index');
      if(current_index != correct_index) {
        if(fail) fail.call(t, this);
        f = true;
        return false;
      } 
    correct_index += o;
    }); 
    if(!f && succ) succ.call(this, this);
    return this;
  }
});
```

Comment: Technically this checks whether the indexes are *consecutive*, not *ordered* ;)

Comment: you got me Felix ... made a huge update to cover that!